# UITextField RightView incorrect sizing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, sizing

**The problem**
[image]

The `rightView` is not properly resized, when the `UITextField` is placed inside an UICollectionView cell inside an `UIStackView`

The code:

```
  func configure(cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
    guard let cell = cell as? ListTextFieldCell else {return}
    self.cell = cell
    cell.title.text = "PIN"
    let textField = cell.textField!
    textField.rightViewMode = .always
    updateButtonTitle()
    textField.rightView = revealPasswordButton
    textField.placeholder = "4 digits"
    textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    textField.delegate = self
    updateButtonTitle()
    // No effect!
    revealPasswordButton.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50))
  }


    // no effect WHATSOEVER
    revealPasswordButton.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
    revealPasswordButton.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    revealPasswordButton.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    revealPasswordButton.sizeToFit()
  }
```

On the other hand, in a normal `UIView` the very same code produces the correct result:

[image]

**What could be the case of such a problem**

Comment: Have you tried setting a background color for the textfield and saw?

Answer (score 0):

What is your `UIStackView` Distribution settings? Also you might want to set the `contentCompressionResistancePriority` Horizontal value to be `UILayoutPriorityDefaultRequired` for the `rightView`